# PHP Include of a file in a Child file - HTTP Status Code 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, include-path

I'm having a Main PHP file and two DTO under a folder, the folder structure is

```
   Root
    |
    |_ DTO
    |   |_ AddressDTO.php
    |   |_ StateDTO.php
    |
    |_ Main.php
```

DTO Class : `StateDTO.php`

```
<?php
class StateDTO
{
    public $StateId;
    public $Name;

    public function __construct($stateId, $name)
    {
        $this->StateId = $stateId;
        $this->Name    = $name;
    }
}
?>
```

DTO Class : `AddressDTO.php`

```
<?php
include("./DTO/StateDTO.php");

class AddressDTO
{
    public $AddressId;
    public $AddressLine1;
    public $AddressLine2;
    public $City;
    public $PIN;
    public $State;

    public function AddState($stateId, $name)
    {
        $this->State = new StateDTO($stateId, $name);
    }
}
?>
```

Main PHP File : `Main.php`

```
<?php
include("./DTO/AddressDTO.php");

$obj = new AddressDTO();

?>
```

I'm getting `HTTP Status Code 500` (Internal Server Error) while on calling `Main.php`

I not sure whether the `include("./DTO/StateDTO.php");` is correct in `AddressDTO.php` but I tried `include("./StateDTO.php");` too I filed.

Comment: in file AddressDTO.php change include("./DTO/StateDTO.php");
to include("./StateDTO.php");

Comment: @shantanu I tried that too...

Comment: Check your server's error log.